# Terraform API Gateway CORS Integration Response Output passthrough is seemingly wrong

Tags: terraform, cors, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to add CORS to my REST API via terraform. All the lambda proxy integrations work except cors. I've manually created one in the UI and verified CORS works. The only difference I can see between the two is the Output passthrough is set to `No` in the one that works and is always populated with `Yes` in my terraform configurations that is failing cors.

here is my API provisioning

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api" {
  name = "${local.app_name}-${local.environment}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "rest_api_resource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "gmail"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "rest_api_post_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "rest_api_get_method_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.rest_api_post_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "rest_api_post_method_response_200" {
  rest_api_id         = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id         = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method         = aws_api_gateway_method.rest_api_post_method.http_method
  status_code         = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true,
  }

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "cors_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.rest_api_post_method.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.rest_api_post_method_response_200.status_code

  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = ""
  }
}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_gateway_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.region}:${local.aws_account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}/*/*"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "rest_api_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  triggers    = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id,
      aws_api_gateway_method.rest_api_post_method.id,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.rest_api_get_method_integration.id
    ]))
  }
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "rest_api_stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.rest_api_deployment.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  stage_name    = local.environment
}

output "rest_api_url" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.rest_api_deployment.invoke_url}${aws_api_gateway_stage.rest_api_stage.stage_name}${aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.path}"
}
```

Then I am attempting to add cors like so

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "cors_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method   = "OPTIONS"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "cors_integration" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.cors_method.http_method
  type                 = "MOCK"
  passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
  content_handling     = "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
  request_templates    = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode({
      statusCode = 200
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "cors" {
  depends_on          = [aws_api_gateway_method.cors_method]
  rest_api_id         = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id         = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method         = aws_api_gateway_method.cors_method.http_method
  status_code         = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true,
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true
  }
  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "cors" {
  depends_on          = [aws_api_gateway_integration.cors_integration, aws_api_gateway_method_response.cors]
  rest_api_id         = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id         = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_resource.id
  http_method         = aws_api_gateway_method.cors_method.http_method
  status_code         = 200
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = "'*'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET, POST, OPTIONS'"
    # remove or add HTTP methods as needed
  }

}
```

I even tried using the https://github.com/squidfunk/terraform-aws-api-gateway-enable-cors instead.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Here is what I am talking about, left works and was created through UI, right fails via terraform though I am not sure how this is set

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems it's a bit different for a mocked API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#apigateway-enable-cors-mock.

Comment: I did add the headers to my lambda code to return as well so I think I have that covered? @MarkoE

Comment: Could be, I am not sure what does `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'request-originating server addresses'`?

Comment: I think they just mean that it needs to be replaced. I have it returning the `*` which should mean from anywhere is fine @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

Presumably with any data in the **response_templates** and/or **response_parameters** block, 'Output passthrough' switches to **Yes**.

I ran into the same problem and in my case it was solved by removing the response_templates = {...} section in the aws_api_gateway_integration_response resource.